# Woocommerce - list all prices

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to write some php to display a list of all current prices (including variations) in Woocommerce.

I'm very new to php so I'm not too sure what I'm doing.

I've been using this code to output a list of all page and product permalinks:

```
<?php

include "wp-load.php";

$posts = new WP_Query('post_type=any&posts_per_page=-1&post_status=publish');
$posts = $posts->posts;
/*
global $wpdb;
$posts = $wpdb->get_results("
    SELECT ID,post_type,post_title
    FROM {$wpdb->posts}
    WHERE post_status<>'auto-draft' AND post_type NOT IN ('revision','nav_menu_item')
");
*/

header('Content-type:text/plain');
foreach($posts as $post) {
    switch ($post->post_type) {
        case 'revision':
        case 'nav_menu_item':
            break;
        case 'page':
            $permalink = get_page_link($post->ID);
            break;
        case 'post':
            $permalink = get_permalink($post->ID);
            break;
        case 'attachment':
            $permalink = get_attachment_link($post->ID);
            break;
        default:
            $permalink = get_post_permalink($post->ID);
            break;
    }
    echo "\n{$post->post_type}\t{$permalink}\t{$post->post_title}";
}
```

Which works very well. But I've tried to adapt it like this:

```
<?php

include "wp-load.php";

$posts = new WP_Query('post_type=any&posts_per_page=-1&post_status=publish');
$posts = $posts->posts;
/*
global $wpdb;
$posts = $wpdb->get_results("
    SELECT ID,post_type,post_title
    FROM {$wpdb->posts}
    WHERE post_status<>'auto-draft' AND post_type NOT IN ('revision','nav_menu_item')
");
*/

header('Content-type:text/plain');
foreach($posts as $post) {
    switch ($post->post_type) {
        case 'revision':
    global $product;
        return $name.' '.$product->get_price_html();

    }
    echo "\n{$post->post_type}\t{$permalink}\t{$post->get_price_html}";
}
```

But this is obviously not working. It just outputs a list of post types.

Can anyone help me adapt this to a script that will output a list of product names with their associated prices, including variations?? Many thanks in advance, I'm off to study php!

Comment: what are you trying to achieve when adapting the code?

Comment: Hi danyo. What I'm trying to achieve is a output list of all Woocommerce products with their _prices_ (including product "variants") so that I can use this information to create an acurate datafeed for Google PLAs. Ultimately I'd like to create a script that extracts _all_ the info in the right format for the datafeed but this is a bit above my level at the moment. The first code example works perfectly to create a list of all URLs ("permalinks") so I imagined it wouldn't be too hard to adapt to include prices as well. "Variable" products (two prices, one URL) might be the stumbling block here

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need:

```
<ul>
    <?php
    foreach (get_posts('post_type=product&post_status=publish') as $product) {
        $product = get_product($product->ID);
        if ($product->product_type == "variation")
            continue;

        if ($product->product_type = "variable") {
            ?><li><?php echo $product->post->post_title . ": " . $product->get_price_html(); ?>
                <ul><?php foreach($product->get_children() as $child) { ?>
                    <li><?php $child_product = $product->get_child($child->variation_id); 
                              echo $child_product->post->post_title . ": " . $product->get_price_html(); ?>
                    </li><?php } ?>
                </ul>
            </li><?php
        } else {
            ?><li><?php
        }
    }
    ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi Liam. I couldn't get that to work sorry. I'm actually using a plugin now to create the datafeed so no biggy. Thanks anyway :)